# Spark: map columns of a dataframe to their ID of the distinct elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have the following dataframe of two columns of string type A and B:

```
val df = (
    spark
    .createDataFrame(
        Seq(
            ("a1", "b1"),
            ("a1", "b2"),
            ("a1", "b2"),
            ("a2", "b3")
        )
    )
).toDF("A", "B")
```

I create maps between distinct elements of each columns and a set of integers

```
val mapColA = (
    df
    .select("A")
    .distinct
    .rdd
    .zipWithIndex
    .collectAsMap
)

val mapColB = (
    df
    .select("B")
    .distinct
    .rdd
    .zipWithIndex
    .collectAsMap
)
```

Now I want to create a new columns in the dataframe applying those maps to their correspondent columns. For one map only this would be

```
df.select("A").map(x=>mapColA.get(x)).show()
```

However I don't understand how to apply each map to their correspondent columns and create two new columns (e.g. with `withColumn`). The expected result would be

```
val result = (
    spark
    .createDataFrame(
        Seq(
            ("a1", "b1", 1, 1),
            ("a1", "b2", 1, 2),
            ("a1", "b2", 1, 2),
            ("a2", "b3", 2, 3)
        )
    )
).toDF("A", "B", "idA", "idB")
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this can be achieved using `dense_rank`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df.withColumn("idA", dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("A")))
            .withColumn("idB", dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("B")))

df2.show
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|idA|idB|
+---+---+---+---+
| a1| b1|  1|  1|
| a1| b2|  1|  2|
| a1| b2|  1|  2|
| a2| b3|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+
```

If you want to stick with your original code, you can make some modifications:

```
val mapColA = df.select("A").distinct().rdd.map(r=>r.getAs[String](0)).zipWithIndex.collectAsMap

val mapColB = df.select("B").distinct().rdd.map(r=>r.getAs[String](0)).zipWithIndex.collectAsMap

val df2 = df.map(r => (r.getAs[String](0), r.getAs[String](1), mapColA.get(r.getAs[String](0)), mapColB.get(r.getAs[String](1)))).toDF("A","B", "idA", "idB")

df2.show
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|idA|idB|
+---+---+---+---+
| a1| b1|  1|  2|
| a1| b2|  1|  0|
| a1| b2|  1|  0|
| a2| b3|  0|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Very nice suggestion! However, I get a `WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.` error, in a larger dataset. I wonder if there's a better way to do the same task

Comment: @Galuoises I added an alternative way which builds on your original code. See if that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the code! It's exactly what I was trying to build